Populate new columns with a header value
I try to automate as much as possible the creation of a new column and populate it with a unique "header value". I would like to automate it as much as possible and not use any additional columns to process data.
Start table
                   Paid Forcecasted Forcecasted
Person A    Item 1  10€     23€ 
Person A    Item 2          22€        7€
Person A    Item 3  30€     10€       15€
Person B    Item 4  5€      7€        30€
Person B    Item 5  10€     40€        6€
Person B    Item 6  10€     5€         8€
Person C    Item 7  2€      9€
Person C    Item 8  4€      

Expected result
Person A    Item 1  10  Paid    23  Forcecasted     Forcecasted
Person A    Item 2      Paid    22  Forcecasted 7   Forcecasted
Person A    Item 3  30  Paid    10  Forcecasted 15  Forcecasted
Person B    Item 4  5   Paid    7   Forcecasted 30  Forcecasted
Person B    Item 5  10  Paid    40  Forcecasted 6   Forcecasted
Person B    Item 6  10  Paid    5   Forcecasted 8   Forcecasted
Person C    Item 7  2   Paid        Forcecasted 9   Forcecasted
Person C    Item 8  4   Paid        Forcecasted     Forcecasted

I managed to succeed with the following formula =HSTACK(A2:B9;arrayformula(split(FLATTEN(C2:C9&"/"&C1);"/";;0));arrayformula(split(FLATTEN(D2:D9&"/"&D1);"/";;0));arrayformula(split(FLATTEN(E2:E9&"/"&E1);"/";;0)))
It does the job but I am sure there is a more simple way of doing it as I repeat 3 times the sequence. I initially wanted to use Query, but I do not manage to create a new column and populate it with computed data.
I could also do something very basic, which is to create 3 columns and repeat the header value inside, then query the whole thing
I am certain there a smarter, quicker ways of doing.
Many thanks!!

For a table like your 'start table', with any number of rows (but just the five columns shown), you can use the following:
=let(
hdr;C1:E1;
tbl;filter(A2:E;A2:A<>"");
{choosecols(tbl;1;2)\byrow(choosecols(tbl;3;4;5);lambda(row;torow({row;hdr};;1)))})

We are using torow to interlace your data and headers into a single row, calling it on a row-by-row basis within byrow.

Hello! Thank you very much, I will learn from it although I did not manage to make it work

Sorry - my mistake (wrong locale for formula in original answer) - I have updated my answer and it should work for you now.

No worries, many thanks!!


Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(Σ;A2:E9; Λ;lambda(x;wrapcols(x;rows(Σ);x)); Ξ;lambda(x;choosecols(Σ;x)); 
 {Ξ(sequence(3))\Λ(C1)\Ξ(4)\Λ(D1)\Ξ(5)\Λ(E1)})



Hello! Thank you very much, it is very useful

I don't know if this is a more simple method, but here's something you could try with LET, CHOOSECOLS, BYROW/LAMBDA, and INDEX.
=LET(header;C1:E1;BYROW(A2:E9;LAMBDA(k;hstack(CHOOSECOLS(k;1;2;3);index(header;1;1);index(k;;4);index(header;1;2);index(k;;5);index(header;1;3)))))


Hello! Thank you very much, it is very useful
